# Laravel Facades global Facade for each individual class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

The concept of Facades is something new to me and the structure that Laravel uses to organize it seems over cluttered.

```
app    
└───Facades
│   │   Facade.php
│   │
│   └───Classes
│       │   Facade.php
│       │
```

**app/Facades/Facade.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Facade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'Facade';
    }
}
```

**app/Facades/Classes/Facade.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades\Classes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Facade extends Facade
{
    // Logic Here
}
```

What I want to do is combine the two of these together so I just have files in `app/Facades` but it doesn't seem there is a way to do that because Laravel relies on having the structure shown.

Are there any options to get this into a single file so I don't have tons of duplications?

Comment: then you don't want a facade sounds like and there is no specific structure, facades are just static proxies for something else

Comment: @lagbox That's some of my confusion with using Facades, I don't really see the point when you can just make static properties within your class.

Comment: static proxy, you are not calling static methods on the proxied class ... the facade resolves an instance then proxies the method call on the instance ... creates a means to interact with an instance through a static call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend `Facades` when you are using the class' namespace. For instance, let's say you have a `Foo` class:

```php
// app/Foo.php

namespace App;

class Foo
{
    public function bar() : string
    {
        return 'Hello world!';
    }
}
```

Then you can do this in your controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Facades\App\Foo;

class TestController
{
    public function __invoke() : void
    {
        echo Foo::bar(); // Hello world!
    }
}
```

With this approach, you do not need to "duplicate" your files.

For more information about real time facades: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades#real-time-facades

Comment: I keep getting `Target class [App\Facades\Foo] does not exist.`

Comment: @JoeScotto Because it's `Facades\App\Foo`, not `App\Facades\Foo`.

Comment: It was my namespacing on the Foo class, it's working now. Is there any benefit to using Facades though because it seems that you can just use a static function instead.

Comment: A facade is not using static methods of the class. It uses an instance of the class behind the scenes.